# Hook Onload event to Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, onload

What is the javascript code to hook two onload events to an iframe and to happen on different onload attempts.

I want the first onload to do nothing but the next onload to redirect.  Is this possible?

Comment: how is that your iframe receives two onload events?

Comment: the first is when iframe is loaded. second is when iframe is submitted and results are shown

Comment: do you control the results that are shown, you could put in the result page javascript to do the redirect.

Comment: no i don't control the results

Comment: how is the url that gets loaded the second time? you could match for that in your onload event and only redirect if it's the result page pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**

After re-reading your question, I realized you wanted the functions to to trigger on separate events. This is easier to achieve:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('daiframe');

ifr.onload = function(){
    ifr.onload = function(){
        // do the redirect here
    };
};


ifr.src = 'http://initial.url/';
```

What is of utmost importance here is that you set the onload code above BEFORE the iframe gets the initial URL, like I did. Assuming you are writing the iframe HTML code directly, be sure that the SRC attribute points to `about:blank`.

**Edit:** *From information given in comment and my earlier warning...*

Let's say the PHP part looks like this:

```
$code = '<iframe src="http://some.url/"></iframe>';
echo $code;
```

That code needs to be changed to:

```
$code = '<iframe src="http://some.url/"></iframe>';
echo str_replace('<iframe ', '<iframe onload="ifrLoaded();" ', $code);

?><script type="text/javascript">
    var alreadyLoaded = false;
    function ifrLoaded(){
        if(alreadyLoaded){
            // do your redirect
        }else{
            alreadyLoaded = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

**Old Answer**

Something like this?

```
function appendEvent(el, name, fn){
    if(typeof el[name] == 'function'){
        var oldfn = el[name];
        el[name] = function(){
            oldfn.apply(this, arguments);
            fn.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }else{
        el[name] = fn;
    }
}


var ifr = document.getElementById('daiframe');

appendEvent(ifr, 'onload', function(){});
appendEvent(ifr, 'onload', function(){ /* do the redirect */ });

ifr.src = 'http://target.url/'; // since onload fires only after the URL is set
```

[A working JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/r9FZX/1/)

Comment: I don't think that's the OP is looking for. He would like one single event handler, but different behavior on different loading.

Comment: what goes in ifr.src = 'http://initial.url/';???? i do not host the iframe, just pull the form in from an iframe from an affiliate using an <iframe></iframe> code

Comment: @user1684086 You will have to modify the iframe code then. I'm editing my answer to show a demo.

Comment: But you have the url inside the <iframe> tag (from the src attribute), no?